# Find details for minimum price entry for each group of rows with the same article number

Tags: mysql, sorting, grouping, greatest-n-per-group

I read a lot about this, but none worked for me. Can someone help?

I have a big table with a lot of different articles (a lot with same EAN) and need always only the cheapest one (sort by price) with the correct AN:

```
*art   price   an    ean
*Test |79,00|15770|0808736558136
*Test |85,00|k3238|0808736558136
*Test |68,00|r4850|0808736558136
*Test |65,00|a1117|0808736558136
*Test |78,00|t8619|0808736558136
```

Expect this one:

```
*Test |65,00|a1117|0808736558136
```

Comment: Do you care to edit the question heading?  This is not really about sort before group by, although I do understand why you expected that kind of solution.

Comment: Sorry , i'm not pretty good in findig english explanations for my problme :-)

Comment: It's always easier in retrospection.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT B.*
  FROM BigTable AS B -- Why do SQL questions omit the table names so often?
  JOIN (SELECT EAN, MIN(Price) AS Price
          FROM BigTable
         GROUP BY EAN
       ) AS P
    ON B.EAN = P.EAN AND B.Price = P.Price
 ORDER BY B.EAN;
```

The sub-query finds the minimum price for each EAN; the outer query finds the details that match the EAN and minimum price for that EAN.  If there are two records with the same minimum price for a given EAN, both will be chosen.

Comment: Mysql Error: Column 'ean' in order clause is ambiguous

Comment: OK - disambiguate.  It isn't all that hard to do.  :D   I'll fix.

Comment: Hello together ! Since upgrade to mysql 5.1.69 the above grouping does not work anymore. In BigTable i have a lot of duplicate EANs which are not grouped but why ? <code>*art   price   an    ean
*Test |79,00|15770|0808736558136
*Test |79,00|a1234|0808736558136
*Test |79,00|b1234|0808736558136
*Test |79,00|c1234|0808736558136
</code>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That works for the the single EAN with the lowest price; but doesn't generalize very well.  You can add a WHERE clause to specify the single EAN you're after, but if you're after many?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : but we dind't order by EAN .... so if the ean(s) are the same, where is the problem? Probably i still misreading the question

Comment: This will work for the sample data where there is just one EAN.  In the BigTable, there will be many EANs, but your query will still return just one row, rather than one row per distinct EAN.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : ok, now i got it.. The "output expected" drive me out of way because doesn't provide plus than one row ...